Safe encapsulation for many variables C++
I rewrote my blackjack game in C++ to take more of an OOP approach. One thing I know for sure is that class variables aren't meant to be public for safety reasons and if the variable is needed standalone, you are supposed to create getters and setters for it. The problem is that my code in main.cpp uses these variables too often. Besides there are so many of them, that setting up every one of them, would be - well - annoying.
For example, this is a piece of the Account and Hand class:
class Account {
private:
    std::fstream saveFile;
public:
    std::string name;
    int tokenAmount, betAmount;

    bool doubledDown, splitted;
    bool canDoubleDown, canSplit;
    int choseToStand;

    void registerUser();
    void saveBalance();
//[...](constructor)

class Hand {
public:
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> cards;
    std::pair<bool, bool> handBusted;
    int cardSum;

    void display();
    int sum();
    bool checkForBj();
};

A line of this code:
std::cout << "Decision: [1] Stand, [2] Hit";
if (!player.splitted && !player.doubledDown && roundNumber == 1 && player.betAmount <= player.tokenAmount) {
    std::cout << ", [3] Double down";
    player.canDoubleDown = true;
}

would be so full of these functions, that it would become unreadable, or maybe I'm just uneducated enough.
My question is, does it make sense to set up getters and setters in my case, and if so, does it require me to rewrite this code or is it supposed to look like this? because I genuinely don't know.

Always you need getters and setters, you brake encapsulation. Even if it looks better as public members, you have external access into your class which is in a perfect world not needed. If you need getters/setters, think again about your design!

The data members are next to never unrelated to each other and setting one would more often than not make information in some other member incorrect. So prefer bigger operations. For example from your logic that canDoubleDown looks not like a flag but member function that needs roundNumber as input for to decide its value.

you should take this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ , one thing i can point out is that your account class is more like a state machine, maybe you should read about state machines.

If you are worried about the efficiency of getters and setters, define them inside the class declaration.  This will make them inline so that the compiler doesn't generate the call-and-return interface that most functions use.  Profile again.

You can move those functions / conditions into the class.  So instead of having the long condition in main, you would have something like this:
bool Account::CanDoubleDown() {
  return !splitted && !doubledDown && (betAmount <= tokenAmount);
}

Which would probably also eliminate the canSplit and canDoubleDown member variables - they should be bool-returning member functions.
From the context you've given it's not clear where roundNumber comes from, so it could either be a parameter, or it could be the one condition remaining in main():
if(roundNumber == 1 && player.CanDoubleDown()) {
   std::cout << ", [3] Double down";
}

There's not enough context to know for sure, but there's no need to store canDoubleDown as a boolean in Account - the member function is fine.

CanDoubleDown would need int roundNumber as a parameter (or bool isRoundOne)

Possibly, but there's not a lot of context in the original question - it's not "runnable" code.  I'll add it to my answer though.

int roundNumber only function is to determine whether the player can double down or not, so yes I could replace it, but i added it in case of upcoming features. I know what OOP is, but I didn't really have a chance to understand where to implement it and you explained it perfectly

@dheb Glad to help!  If this answered your question sufficiently, you can "accept" the answer too.
